# Correct way of listening for a specific key with pygobject?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I am very new to programming with python and gtk. After a day of googling and trying to find documentation i came up with the following solution for reacting on a press of a given button:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk,Gdk

class BNWrestling(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self, bnt):
        self.connect("key_press_event",self.on_key_press)

    def on_key_press(self,widget,eventkey):
        keyval = eventkey.get_keyval()[1] #very ugly here
        if keyval == Gdk.KEY_Left:
            do_sth()
```

This code does what it should, however, I am not sure if this is the way it's supposed to be done. Especially the way how I retrieve the keyval seems not to be that elegant.
Is there a nicer way?

Thanks for advice or directions to some documentation (I couldn't find any).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the keyval name (same as the GDK_KEY_XXX constants without the prefix):

```
def on_key_press_event(self, widget, event, user_data=None):
    key = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
    if key == "Left":
        do_something()
        return True
    return False
```